# What should a void*/std::size_t function argument pair be changed to for an interface that writes binary files?

Tags: c++

The C++ core guidelines state many times that using `void*` as an argument is at best confusing and at worst error-prone. My favorite mention is at the end:

[C++ Core Guidelines: To-do: Unclassified proto-rules](http://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#to-do-unclassified-proto-rules)

> Anyone writing a public interface which takes or returns void* should have their toes set on fire.
>   That one has been a personal favorite of mine for a number of years. :)

That said:

What should this function signature be changed to in order to comply with this suggestion? Currently it works with anything, that can be reinterpreted as a `const char*`:

```
bool writeBufferToFile(void* buffer, std::size_t size, const std::string& filePath) const
{
    namespace FS = std::filesystem;
    FS::path p(filePath);
    p.make_preferred();
    bool not_valid_path = FS::is_directory(p);
    bool invalid = not_valid_path;
    if(invalid) { return false; }

    std::ofstream ofs;
    ofs.open(p.string(), std::ios_base::binary);
    if(ofs)
    {
        ofs.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(buffer), size);
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: This is overkill, `void*` is there for a reason.

Comment: I believe the comment you cite is aimed at interfaces that try to use `void*` to achieve polymorphism, which C++ has _way_ better and safer tools for. In the context of working with plain old binary data, raw pointer + size makes sense. Just look at the the signature of the function ultimately doing your work: `basic_ostream::write(const char_type* s, std::streamsize count)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with [`std::any`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/any). It can be used as a type-safe replacement for `void*`.

Motivating articles:

- [std::any: How, when, and why](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/stdany-how-when-and-why/)
- [std::any - comparison with void* and motivating examples](https://www.nextptr.com/tutorial/ta1571648512/stdany-comparison-with-void-and-motivating-examples)

```cpp
bool WriteBufferToFile(const std::any& buffer, std::size_t size, std::filesystem::path filepath) noexcept {
    namespace FS = std::filesystem;
    filepath = FS::absolute(filepath);
    filepath.make_preferred();
    const auto not_valid_path = FS::is_directory(filepath);
    const auto invalid = not_valid_path;
    if(invalid) {
        return false;
    }

    if(std::ofstream ofs{filepath, std::ios_base::binary}; ofs.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&buffer), size)) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you want is not two parameters, a pointer and a size, but one parameter that represents a binary chunk of data. In an ideal world, you might use something like `std::vector<std::uint8_t> const&`, but the problem with this is that it forces callers to do an allocate/copy/free if they happen to store the data some other way.

So what you really want is a class that represents a binary chunk of data but doesn't own that data and can be constructed, copied, and destroyed very cheaply regardless of how the underlying data is stored. This avoids the need to have two parameters to express one concept.

A class that encapsulates this is often called a [`Slice`](https://github.com/ripple/rippled/blob/develop/src/ripple/basics/Slice.h). So I would suggest:

```
class Slice
{
private:
    std::uint8_t const* data_;
    std::size_t size_;
  ...
};

bool writeBufferToFile (const Slice& data, const std::string& filePath) const
```

Your `Slice` class can easily be constructed from a `std::vector <std::uint8_t>` or pretty much any other sensible way of holding a range of bytes.

Comment: But that's just moving the problem to one of the [Slice constructors!](https://github.com/ripple/rippled/blob/fa57859477441b60914e6239382c6fba286a0c26/src/ripple/basics/Slice.h#L59) :/

Comment: This is just sweeping dirt under the rug. A generic pointer and a size in a pretty box are still a generic pointer and a size. The box doesn't solve any problem.

Comment: `std::uint8_t` isn't guaranteed to be some char type, suitable to alias any type. This may be UB on some platforms

Comment: @n.m. It solves the problem of needing to explode a single thing (such as a vector, array, or the like) into two things with confusing code at every call site. With appropriate constructors and other code, calls to `writeBufferToFile` will look clean everywhere and there will be no risk of mismatched parameters.

Comment: @Casey You can use that constructor if you have no better choice. The point is to provide better choices. (Sure, you may still have to interoperate with people who haven't made better choices.)